# Adding a footnote for an author

Tags: footnotes, amsart

```
     \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd\maketitle
      {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
        {}
        {}{}
  \patchcmd\maketitle
        {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
       {\the\toks@}
         {}
         {}{}
    %----
   %\patchcmd\@settitle
   %  {\uppercasenonmath\@title}
   % {}
   %  {}{}
    \patchcmd\@setauthors
          {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
          {\authors}
           {}{}
 \makeatother
  %------------------------------------------------------------
 %\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{url}
   %-----------------               
  %------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   %------------------------------------------------------------
 \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

%-------------------------------------------
 \address{$^{[1]}$ The address of author1.}
  \email{\url{Author1@....com}}
    \address{$^{[2]}$ The address of author2.}
 \email{\url{Author2@....com}}

 \subjclass[2010]{......}

    \keywords{......}

  %%%%%%%%%%%% \begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{document}
 \author[Author1, Author2] {Author1$^{1}$ and Author2$^{2}$ }
 \title{Title}
 \maketitle
 \end{document}
```

> How to add a `*` that indicates that the author 2 is the corresponding author like [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10445)?

[image: g]

Comment: You could use `\thanks` and specify either "author 2" or the author's name; there won't be any footnote marker.  (If you're submitting this to the AMS, the `^[1]` and `^[2]` will be removed -- the "bare" values for these elements are needed for the bibliographic information provided to indexing services.  (I don't know what other publishers do in this situation.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your comment however I don't understand how to use `\thanks` and if I remove `$^{[1]}$` what should I use? Thank you very much.

Comment: For `amsart`, `\thanks` is parallel to the address commands.  Each such command should follow the appropriate `\author` and the order will be respected.  An appropriate entry for this case would be `\thanks{The second author is the corresponding author.}`  This will appear at the bottom of the first page as an unlabeled footnote.  The addresses will appear in the order given at the end of the article.  Other document classes will give different results, so I'm adding `amsart` to the tags for the question.

Comment: I will geatfull if you provide me an answer because if I delete `$^{[1]}$` I cannot distinct between the two authors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method applies only to `amsart`.  Other article document classes work differently.

Enter authors and their associated information as follows:

```
\author{Author 1}
\address{Address for Author 1}
\email{Author1@xxx.com}

\author{Author 2}
\address{Address for Author 2}
\email{Author2@yyy.com}
\thanks{The second author is the corresponding author.}
```

It is important to enter the elements associated with an author immediately after the `\author` line.  These elements will be kept in the same order as supplied.

The `\thanks` items will be listed, in the order entered, at the bottom of the first page, without a footnote marker.

Addresses will be listed at the end of the article, in the order supplied.  The order is assumed to be in the same order as the authors are listed on the first page.  If necessary, a name can be associated as an option with any address element:

```
\address[Author 2]{Address for Author 2}
```

The author information is implemented in this manner so that each element is separate and distinct, and can be extracted automatically as part of the bibliographic reference for the article.  This is supplied by the publisher to indexing services, for which each element must be individually retrievable.  In the published article, the appearance of each element follows the specified journal style.

Comment: Thank you very much but this not answer my question. My goal is to add a `*` e author 2. Also by removing `$^[1]$` the numbers of authors dispear.

Comment: Also in some situations the two authors have the same adress.

Comment: @Schüler -- Unfortunately, `amsart` does not support numbering of the authors.  If this were submitted to the AMS for publication with added numbering, that would be removed, for the reason regarding the requirements of indexing services.  (Numbers are assigned internally, to keep the elements for each author associated correctly, but never printed.)

Comment: Please see the following paper, I would like to get like it. https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.10445

Comment: @Schüler -- The paper you cite at the arXiv is available there in source form as well as PDF.  You could retrieve the source files and see how it was produced.  (I'm not able to do that at present.)

Comment: Thank you but please where can I find the sourse file?

Comment: Go to the link that you posted.  On the top right of that page,  under "Download", there is a line "Other formats".  Click on that, and look for the line "Sources".  That should lead to access to the files that will contain the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is not elegant but very quick.

```
    \documentclass[reqno, a4paper]{amsart}

    \title{The article}

    \author{First author}
    \address{FirstAuthorAddress}
    \email{FirstAuthorMail}

    \author{Second author$^{\ast}$}
    \address{SecondAuthorAddress}
    \email{SecondAuthorMail}
    \thanks{$^\ast$Corresponding author.}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!